# Getting "Invoke-RestMethod : The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel" issue in azure pipeline

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

We are building a DevOps Release pipeline and attempting to call the Rest API from the pipeline in a PowerShell script. The Rest API has certificate-based authentication, and we are passing the certificate in the header, but we are receiving the following error:

Invoke-RestMethod : The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

We have performed the below steps:

1. Store the certificate in Azure Library.
2. Downloading the certificate from azure library and installing on current agent.
3. validating the certificate is installed on agent or not.
4. calling the REST API by passing the certificate in header.

Please help me to fix this issue and let me know what I missed or did wrong on my side.

I have passed the all security protocol like Tls11, TLS12 etc. but still getting same issue.

Comment: You can only use TLS 1.2 or 1.3.  Other versions are obsolete.  This issue could be a proxy is enabled and you need to disable the proxy.  TLS is performed before a HTTP Request is sent.  If TLS fails the Request is never sent.  The client request the version of TLS (1.2 or 1.3) and then the server sends back a Certificate block with the names of acceptable certificates.  The client then looks up the certificate names in the stores to find matching certificate.

Comment: The certificate has an encryption mode and both client and server must be able to use the encryption mode.  Older versions of OS and Net do not support newer encryption modes.  If you have a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler you can capture the TLS blocks and check version and certificate names.  You must use HTTPS with TLS (not HTTP).  If a proxy is being used the proxy must also work with the certificate.

Comment: Check the TLS requirements for connecting to azure edge: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databox-online/azure-stack-edge-gpu-configure-tls-settings . Your auth certificate shouldn't be the cause - you would be getting authentication-related errors instead

Comment: @Cpt.Whale : TLS is done before request is sent, so if TLS fails you will NOT get authentication errors because the REQUEST is never sent.

Comment: @jdweng yes exactly. The auth cert has not been sent yet, so it shouldn't be causing this error. Another way to test is simply `Invoke-WebRequest` the same url without headers, and see if you get the same error

Comment: Hi, This [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63940041/azure-devops-powershell-script-could-not-create-ssl-tls-secure-channel) mentions a similar issue as yours. Check the solution whether works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You are not showing any code you are trying.

You must add this to the top of any code you are using to address your scenario(s).

Required for use with web SSL sites

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::
SecurityProtocol = [Net.ServicePointManager]::
SecurityProtocol -bor [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
```

See details:

> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/tls/?view=windowsserver2022-ps
> https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/powershell-gallery-tls-support
> https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Test-TlsProtocols/1.0.0

If you want them all in your code, just because, then this:

```
$AllProtocols = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]'Ssl3,Tls,Tls11,Tls12'
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = $AllProtocols
(Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://idp.safenames.com/").StatusCode
```

So, are you saying you've already done the aforementioned?

Comment: SSL, TLS, TLS11 were all disabled over 2 years ago and should not be used for new code.  It will not work and will cause errors.

Comment: Yes, I have already passed security protocol but still getting the SSL TLS issue.